# Plane-ellipsoid intersection with rational coordinates

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, intersection-theory

Consider an axis-parallel ellipsoid $E_d$ in ${\mathbb R}^d$ that is defined by an equation of the form $a_1x_1^2+\cdots+a_dx_d^2 = r^2$. Consider a hyperplane $h$ that is defined by the equation $b_1x_1+\cdots + b_d x_d = b'$. Assume that $a_1,\ldots,a_d,r^2,b_1,\ldots,b_d,b'$ all rational numbers. Finally, set $E_{d-1} = E_d\cap h_d$.

Given that $E_{d-1}$ is a $(d-2)$-dimensional ellipsoid (as expected), we consider it as living in ${\mathbb R}^{d-1}$ (that is, in $h_d$). Is it true that $E_{d-1}$ can desribed using an equation with rational coefficients? (Moving to ${\mathbb R}^{d-1}$ makes $E_{d-1}$ a hypersurface so it is again defined by a single equation. We can also rotate the space to have $E_{d-1}$ axis parallel.)

Comment: You are asking, in essence, if you can eliminate one variable and obtain an equation with rational coefficients for $E_{d-1}$.  Have you tried doing this?  The rotation of axes (to make $E_{d-1}$ "axis parallel") can introduce irrationals, so perhaps you should explain what the priority is.

Comment: I started a draft answer but it seems to have vanished sometime in the past week.  I noted that the intersection can be described using an equation with rational coefficients, though it seems the desire is to do this in a fairly restricted (isometric) way.  If the rational ellipsoid were a sphere, then the suggested program (intersect and rotate to an axis-parallel hyperplane) can be carried out to give a rational sphere of one less dimension.